# Java getAttribute() method error in the servlet

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, getattribute

I am Facing an issue while trying to get **sum** element in one servlet from the other by using Request Dispatcher.

But the getAttribute() method in S2.java is giving error while accessing the sum from Request_Dispatcher_example.java.

I have tried this using HttpSession as well but the same error is occurred there

```
  **Error:**
    
    Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)" is null
```

> Type Exception Report
> Message Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of
> "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)" is null
> Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of
> "javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getAttribute(String)" is null
> com.servlet.S2.doGet(S2.java:22)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

**Code**

**1. Request_Dispatcher_example.java**

```
public class Request_Dispatcher_example extends HttpServlet

{
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String i = req.getParameter("n1");
        String j = req.getParameter("n2");
        
        int nn1= Integer.parseInt(i);
        int nn2 = Integer.parseInt(j);
        
        int s = nn1 + nn2;
        
        req.setAttribute("sum", s);
        
        
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("s2");
        rd.forward(req, res);
        
    }
}
```

**2. S2.java**

```
public class S2 extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        
        
        int nn1  = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("n1"));
        int nn2  = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("n2"));

        int p = nn1*nn2;
        int sum = (Integer) req.getAttribute("sum");
        
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("Sum : "+sum);
        out.println("Product : "+p);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Got the solution for this error:**

In this case, I did not map my first java servlet file  Request_Dispatcher_example.java in an xml file.

But now after mapping it in xml it is working fine and giving the proper results.

**Specifically :  we need to map our all the servlet files to xml to overcome this issue**

Thank you!